# How to get Django Report Builder working properly?

Tags: django, django-admin

Documentation provided by Burke isn't very thorough and there isn't a lot of information on Django Report Builder yet, not even youtube videos. Does anybody have any information on how to get work Report Builder Working in Django? I currently keep getting this error message:

(1146, "Table 'epic_test2.report_builder_report' doesn't exist")

I've installed it, but I can't create reports yet and the documentation I do have isn't very helpful. Any advice would be great! Thanks!

UPDATE TO POST/ 5.12.15 -

I fixed the first issue, but now I have a new error. :) Yay. It's a Field Error

"Cannot Resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: app_label, id, logentry, model, permission, report.

ANY clues for this one would be helpful... going into third hour of troubleshooting. :)

Thanks!
~Heather

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to run a migrate to create the Report Builder tables required.

python manage.py migrate

Comment: Thank you for answering! I've done that. I got past the first error... now I have this error: "Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: app_label, id, logentry, model, permission, report."

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do a full search in your code for "name", something like: `grep -R "name" .`, and see where it's defined, is it a valid field in models.py, etc.

I've had similar error before, turned out, I updated my variable name from something like "name" to "new_name" in my model. The way report-builder works, it saves column (field) name in the database. If it's an old field name, there will be error.  Luckily this is easy to fix:  go to report-builder UI, remove the row for that column, then add the column back, then the new field name would be saved.

Hope this helps.